# Create with Include Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

recently I discovered [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations) on the sequelize documentation where you can create using include. Now I trying to do it on my program but only creates the records of the "parent" model and not for the children.

This is my model and my controller.

```
var MainMenu = sequelize.define('MainMenu', {
    Name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50)      
    },
    Day: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    RecordStatus:{
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    },    
    DeletedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  },
  {
    associate: function(models){
      models.MainMenu.hasMany(models.MainMeal, {as: 'Menu'});
    }
  }
);

exports.createIn = (req, res) => {

 let Menu = {
   Name: 'MenuTest',
   MainMeal: [{
     Type: 'Breakfast',
     Name: 'MealTest1'
   }, {
     Type: 'Lunch',
     Name: 'MealTest2'
   }]
 };

  db.MainMenu.create(Menu, {
    include: [{
      model: db.MainMeal,
      as: 'Menu'
    }]
  })
    .then( mainmenu => {
      if (!mainmenu) {
        return res.send('users/signup', {
          errors: 'Error al registrar el mainmenu.'
        });
      } else {
        return res.jsonp(mainmenu);
      }
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400)
        .send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    });
};
```

On my case it only creates the `MainMenu` record and not the `MainMeal` records. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `menu` object, and include `Menu` array and not `MainMeal`

> - You have to give the aliased name in the object

```
let mainMenu = {
   Name: 'MenuTest',
   Menu: [{
     Type: 'Breakfast',
     Name: 'MealTest1'
   }, {
     Type: 'Lunch',
     Name: 'MealTest2'
   }]
 };
```

Now,

```
db.MainMenu.create(mainMenu, {
    include: [{
      model: db.MainMeal,
      as: 'Menu'
    }]
  })
    .then( mainmenu => {
      if (!mainmenu) {
        return res.send('users/signup', {
          errors: 'Error al registrar el mainmenu.'
        });
      } else {
        return res.jsonp(mainmenu);
      }
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400)
        .send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    });
```

Comment: Omg that worked!. Hahaha funny how just the variable name works. Thank you.

Comment: Now taking advantage of your answer, if I want to do a second `Include` inside MainMenu, first it is possible? do I just add the object or array inside `Menu`?

Answer (score 5):

The main thing is of course the naming of `Menu` should be within the data passed to `.create()` itself, along with the arguments presented there and *if* you really need to specify the alias *"twice"*, which you do not. But there are some other things to be aware of.

I'd personally prefer storing the association as it's own export and including that within the statement. This generally becomes a bit clearer when you understand the usage of that association later.

I would also strongly encourage that when you are "writing" things across multiple tables, then you implement [transactions](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html) to ensure all related items are actually created and not left orphaned should any errors arise.

As a brief listing based on the example:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:menu.db',{ logging: console.log });

const MainMeal = sequelize.define('MainMeal', {
  Type: { type: Sequelize.STRING(50) },
  Name: { type: Sequelize.STRING(50) }
});

const MainMenu = sequelize.define('MainMenu', {
  Name: { type: Sequelize.STRING(50) }
});

MainMenu.Meals = MainMenu.hasMany(MainMeal, { as: 'Menu' });

(async function() {

  try {

    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await MainMeal.sync({ force: true });
    await MainMenu.sync({ force: true });

    let result = await sequelize.transaction(transaction => 
      MainMenu.create({
        Name: 'MenuTest',
        Menu: [
          { Type: 'Breakfast', Name: 'MealTest1' },
          { Type: 'Lunch', Name: 'MealTest2' }
        ]
      },{
        include: MainMenu.Meals,
        transaction
      })
    );

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }
})();
```

Which would output something like:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MainMeals`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MainMeals` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `Type` VARCHAR(50), `Name` VARCHAR(50), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `MainMenuId` INTEGER REFERENCES `MainMenus` (`id`) ON DELETE
SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`MainMeals`)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MainMenus`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MainMenus` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `Name` VARCHAR(50), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`MainMenus`)
Executing (3d645847-56ca-435a-b786-6be62a05e8d5): BEGIN DEFERRED TRANSACTION;
Executing (3d645847-56ca-435a-b786-6be62a05e8d5): INSERT INTO `MainMenus` (`id`,`Name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,'MenuTest','2018-04-14 08:08:17.132 +00:00','2018-04-14 08:08:17.132 +00:00');
Executing (3d645847-56ca-435a-b786-6be62a05e8d5): INSERT INTO `MainMeals` (`id`,`Type`,`Name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`MainMenuId`)
VALUES (NULL,'Breakfast','MealTest1','2018-04-14 08:08:17.152 +00:00','2018-04-14 08:08:17.152 +00:00',1);
Executing (3d645847-56ca-435a-b786-6be62a05e8d5): INSERT INTO `MainMeals` (`id`,`Type`,`Name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`MainMenuId`)
VALUES (NULL,'Lunch','MealTest2','2018-04-14 08:08:17.153 +00:00','2018-04-14 08:08:17.153 +00:00',1);
Executing (3d645847-56ca-435a-b786-6be62a05e8d5): COMMIT;
```

The important part there being the transaction `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` wrapping all of those `INSERT` statements as data is created. Even without the transaction implemented, you still see both items being created along with the related "parent". But the point of the argument is this is where you *"should"* be implementing transactions.

Also note that the ["aliased"](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-elements-of-a-hasmany-or-belongstomany-association) `Menu` as used in the data creation and for subsequent access, is not actually "required" to be included within the `.create()` method on the `include` option. It's "optional" and is already defined under the `.hasMany()` arguments, so you don't really need to do it again.

Even if you did, then that part would still be the "association" as used with the `model` argument:

```
{
  include: {
    model: MainMenu.Meals,
    as: 'Menu'
  },
  transaction
}
```

So that's not to be confused with the original name of the model for the "table" which is referenced, which also might be another point of confusion.

Comment: I give the answer to the other guy cause it odes what I want with just a simple change. But I will try your solution with transaction. Thanks for all you explanation.