# How do I eager load a model after creating it?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models Person and Team. The Person and Team model has multiple associations between them as such;

```
Team.hasOne(Person, { as: 'striker', foreignKey: 'strikerId' });
Team.hasOne(Person, { as: 'support', foreignKey: 'supportId' });
Team.hasOne(Person, { as: 'muscle', foreignKey: 'muscleId' });
Team.hasOne(Person, { as: 'defender', foreignKey: 'defenderId' });
```

to create this I'd use `const team = await Team.create({/*pairs*/});`

How do I eager load team directly after creation?

So instead of receiving;

```
{
  "data": {
    ...
    "strikerId": "782c9318-36c0-419e-9e4a-f1410003d79f",
    "supportId": "8aefe33c-349f-41e0-9f53-b5654e9901fe"
    ...
  }
}
```

I get;

```
 {
  "data": {
    ...
    "striker": {
      "id": "782c9318-36c0-419e-9e4a-f1410003d79f",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "position": "striker"
    },
    "defender": {
      "id": "782c9318-36c0-419e-9e4a-f1410003d79f",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "position": "striker"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried doing `const team = await Team.create({/*pairs*/}, {include: {model: Person, as: 'strikerId'}});`

for a single record

*AND*

`const team = await Team.create({/*pairs*/}, {include: [{model: Person, as: 'striker'}, {model: Person, as: 'defender'}]});`

But they don't work. It just returns the usual object.

I can confirm that in the find methods, they work perfectly.

Comment: I think `options.include` is what you're looking for. See https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create

Comment: Already done that. Still returns the PKs. Can you assist me?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828917/10349590 help?

Comment: No it isn't. I don't want to create additional Models with the include. I just want to eager load the model which was just created.